# Opening metal cans on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, orach-chaim, boneh-soter

According to Halacha, is it permissible to use a can opener to open metal cans on Shabbat? Or no, would it fall under a form of prohibited melacha? If it is a form of prohibited melacha, which one would it be? Is this question a machloket amongst the poskim?

Comment: This is a highly googleable question, and easily found in many if not most works on Hilchot Shabbat, english or hebrew

Comment: If you can't tear toilette paper, I don't know how you're going to get the can open.